# Use REPLACE and LIKE together in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace all the occurences of '-' in a column of a table.
What I need is also to replace the string which exists after the dash and its a random number.

To be more specific this is one of my values:

```
"ANDRIU 5-9, CHAL 152 34, SOMETHING"
```

What I want is to replace this part:

```
-9
```

with an empty space.
The problem is that: 9 can be any number and not necessarily one digit.

So I need something like finding the position of the first comma in the whole string. And the position of the dash and then replacing this based on the index values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres provides the function `regexp_replace()`, which does what you want directly:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '-[0-9]+', ' ')
```

Comment: Magic! For learning purposes: where does the + symbol help and where do you define to stop in the first comma?

Comment: @dkar . . . The documentation explains the regular expressions.  But, [0-9] matches a single digit.  The `+` matches one or more occurrences of the pattern (so multiple digits).  So, the pattern stops at any non-digit.